# Change local printer port out directory

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, printer, print-to-pdf

I want to save PDF at specific location without user interaction in Windows.

To achieve this goal I configured local printer port which saves file in Documents folder.
I want it to be changed to "C:\CIRFSpooler" so that printed files can be saved in specific folder.

I tried to put directory name in port but shows error.
[image]

I followed these steps:

1. Press Win + R to bring up the Run dialog, and type Control Printers,
2. Add a printer Select The printer is not listed Select the last item:
3. Add a local printer… Create a new port.
4. Select Local and Name your Port
5. Select Microsoft XPS Class Driver Name the printer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new local port, the printer wizard expects a file, not a directory. If you specified "C:\CIRFSpooler\file_name.pdf" it would work fine.

Of course, that file may then be overwritten every time you print to it. However, when I tried it the PDF-XChange Lite driver, it created its own file with the title of the document and ignored the name I specified.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use 3rd party tools. I have found a way to get random file name where we need to set Keep Printed Document setting. It will create spool file with incremented number. which can be converted to PDF.

Comment: My method works with any printer driver. The PDF-Xchange driver I used was just to test the idea.